# How do I make sure one function call happens after another

Tags: javascript, async-await

In my web application, there are two javascript functions `submitJob` and `fetchJobs`. I would like to call `fetchJob` in the end of `submitJob` so that the user can see the a new job has been created (`this.jobs` is connected to some display elements). Right now, the database is indeed updated, but there is no update on the front end (unless I refresh the web page). My javascript code looks like the following

```
submitJob: async function() {
  try {                                                                        
    let sel = document.getElementById('jobPriority')                           
    let priority = Number(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);  
    let jobData = {'priority': priority, 'data': ''};                          
    let response = await axios.post('/api/jobs/', json=jobData,                
            {headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.token}});             
  } catch (error) { this.handleError(error); };                                
  this.fetchJobs();                                                     
},                                                                             
fetchJobs: async function() {                                           
  try {                                                                        
    let response = await axios.get('/api/jobs/',                               
            {headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.token}});             
    this.jobs = response.data;                                                 
  } catch (error) { this.handleError(error); };   
},
```

My suspicion is that `fetchJobs` is not called after the `axios.post` has returned. How do I guarantee that? I tried to place `this.fetchJobs()` inside the `try` statement and it doesn't work either.

> update: according to the server log, there was not a GET request. Only a successful POST request. Not sure why that is so.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use `asyncFunc1().then(asyncFunc2)`

Comment: You have to return a promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use promised and asyc in javascript as below

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function add1(x) {
  var a = resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + await a + await b;
}

add1(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 2 seconds.
});

async function add2(x) {
  var a = await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b;
}

add2(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 4 seconds.
});
```

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's code? They already have `await axios.post(...)` within the first function and then call the second function on the line after that.

Comment: Here you have to do submitJob().then( ()=>{fetchJobs()})

Comment: In the OP's code `fetchJobs()` is called *inside* the `submitJob()` function, after a line that had `await`. Shouldn't that have the same effect?

Comment: do not call  this.fetchJobs(); inside submitJob()

Comment: Why? What's the point of the `await` keyword if you can't use it to wait for something?